# I have yet to locate any clearly delineated instruction on how to install a .tar.xz file in ubuntu 22+ using the command prompt only. Anyone?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, tar, 22.10, compression

I have yet to locate any clearly delineated instruction on how to install a .tar.xz file in Ubuntu 22+ using the command prompt only.  Anyone?  I've found so many variations, permutations, and outright falsehoods that I'm counting on the community here that I have always rightly placed my trust in to demystify and bring these uncharted waters into clarity once and for all. Thank you all for your time reading this, as well as your expertise that you will use to answer it.

=)

Ed

Comment: There are many variations because a tar.xz file is just a compressed archive - the procedure for installing will depend on what it contains - see this essentially identical question for other compressed archive formats [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: As @steeldriver has said; its dependent on how the packager created the package, as you're asking about a format created in the 1970s & many variations that achieve the same result exist. The package documents it usually in README, INSTALL or procedures where the package was uploaded/stored (*if it was copied to other locations & you used a copy, you may not find all packages*).  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is the end of that *development* cycle; 22.10 being the first *snapshot* release in the development two year development cycle of 24.04 LTS, and doesn't natively used tarballs

Comment: Thank you all.  I know this seems extremely simple now that you put it so succinctly, but as a newbie who is bananas over Ubuntu’s command line, I’m extremely grateful for you taking the time to break it down to my level and satisfy my fanatical desire for precision. As you point out: there is none to be found in tar.xz files until they are analyzed in an uncompressed format.  Many thanks and blessings on your work and your families.  =)